# Ubuntu 18.04 vim-gtk with python2 support

Tags: vim, python-2.7

I need `vim-gtk` with `python2` support on Ubuntu 18.04.

On Ubuntu 16.04 I used the package `vim-gtk-py2` but I don't see an equivalent package on 18.04. Does anyone know of a `vim` package with `python2` support?

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any available lib package from public source.

Therefore, try to build from source, really an easy way if you follow the instructions in the following links:

- [GitHub: Building Vim from source](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source)
- [GitHub: Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim)